# How to use computed properties of state in swiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to use the computed properties in swiftUI of properties.Requirement wise its simple trying to populate the isThree as partial, all or none option depending on the isAvailable or is Health selected. But it doesn't compile, Am I doing something fundamentally wrong in swift?

```
struct CellData  {
    @State var isAvailableSelected : Bool = false
    @State var isHealthSelected : Bool = false
    @State var isEquipementCategorySelected : Bool = false
    
    @State var isThree : ThreeStateBox?  {
        
        if self.isHealthSelected == true || self.isAvailableSelected == true {
            self.isThree = .partial
        }
        if self.isHealthSelected == true && self.isAvailableSelected == true {
            isThree = .all
        }
        if self.isHealthSelected == false && self.isAvailableSelected == false {
            isThree = .none
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: not possible. Use didSet or willSet or init.

Comment: There is no sense to use @State in model, it works only in View.

Comment: I am trying to change the UI according to that model @Asperi

Comment: now the question would be how to change the UI if something gets change in the model, I have list to display

Comment: It can not compile because for computed properties you must return a value in the closure, not setting it. If you want it to work , you have to reverse the order (test the && cases before the || which will be the default case. As stated in previous comments, computed var may not be state var : as it’s result depends on state var it i acts “like state var”. Also state var are for views. If this code is from a model, use published and a n ObservableObject.

Comment: Interesting that my comment “Look up @Published and ObservableObject” got deleted.

Comment: That's an important comment, should not be deleted , People gets guidance from the comment

Answer (score 3):

This can be achieved using this

```
struct CellData  {
    var isAvailableSelected : Bool = false
    var isHealthSelected : Bool = false
    var isEquipementCategorySelected : Bool = false
    var isThree : ThreeStateBox  {
    if self.isHealthSelected == false && self.isAvailableSelected == false {
            return .none
        }

        if self.isHealthSelected == false || self.isAvailableSelected == false {
            return .partial
        }
        if self.isHealthSelected == true && self.isAvailableSelected == true {
            return .all
        }
        
    }
    
}
```